# I want to get Real Time updates using the Facebook Web Hooks whenever someone fills the Instant Forms and Leads are added

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-webhooks

I want this to be similar to a saas service where people can connect their page and whenever a new lead is added we can send a POST request to an API using Webhook.

I am able to just Read the data but not able to get Real Time Updates, If there is a way out please help

I tried using Open Graph Explorer, its giving me access to read the pages and ad data but its working manually, I want to get the leads in Real Time as soon as they are submitting the form using a webhook or something.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-leadgen/

Comment: Can you list what you've tried till now? List any documentation that you followed & where you got stuck?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-leadgen/

I tried this documentation but I am not able to understand how to get the Notifcations and Updates, that is the last part